# Requested resource '{spyne.examples.django}' not found

Tags: django, spyne

I am trying to develop a soap service in Django using Spyne. I've cloned spyne for app 'Hello_world' in Django application, but I get an error. Could anyone help me with it please?

My codes is similar to the one below:

```
app = Application([HelloWorldService], 'spyne.examples.hello.http',
    in_protocol=HttpRpc(),
    out_protocol=Soap11(),
)
```

but the following error occurs:

```
<faultcode>soap11env:Client.ResourceNotFound</faultcode>
<faultstring>Requested resource '{spyne.examples.django}' not found</faultstring>
<faultactor/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no handler defined for the root url:

https://github.com/plq/spyne/blob/b3b3f198b6148a498cdaeda9897307e0c5b1aac1/examples/django/rpctest/urls.py#L40

After you switch the input protocol to HttpRpc and do this:

```
curl -D - localhost:8000/hello_world/
```

You get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap11env:Body>
<soap11env:Fault>
    <faultcode>soap11env:Client.ResourceNotFound</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Requested resource u'{spyne.examples.django}' not found</faultstring>
    <faultactor></faultactor>
</soap11env:Fault>
</soap11env:Body></soap11env:Envelope>
```

That's because you didn't specify which method to call.

The `HelloWorldService` in that example defines the say_hello function. You can call that.

```
curl -D - "localhost:8000/hello_world/say_hello"
```

Now this finds the method but you get a traceback (which I won't include here) because of non-validated input being passed to your function.

If you pass all the parameters:

```
curl -D - "localhost:8000/hello_world/say_hello?times=5&name=Fatemeh"
```

You get:

```xml
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="spyne.examples.django">
    <soap11env:Body><tns:say_helloResponse>
    <tns:say_helloResult>
        <tns:string>Hello, Fatemeh</tns:string>
        <tns:string>Hello, Fatemeh</tns:string>
        <tns:string>Hello, Fatemeh</tns:string>
        <tns:string>Hello, Fatemeh</tns:string>
        <tns:string>Hello, Fatemeh</tns:string>
    </tns:say_helloResult></tns:say_helloResponse></soap11env:Body></soap11env:Envelope>
```

You may want to enable validation to avoid `Server` exceptions. First we add `Mandatory` markers to input types:

```py
    from spyne import M
    class HelloWorldService(Service):
        @rpc(M(Unicode), M(Integer), _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
        def say_hello(ctx, name, times):
            for i in range(times):
                yield 'Hello, %s' % name
```

Then we enable soft validation (the only one for `HttpRpc`)

```py
app = Application([HelloWorldService], 'spyne.examples.hello.http',
    in_protocol=HttpRpc(validator='soft'),
    out_protocol=Soap11(),
)
```

After server restart and the following:

```
curl -D - "localhost:8000/hello_world/say_hello"
```

You get:

```
<class 'spyne.model.complex.say_hello'>.name member must occur at least 1 times.
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use in_protocol Soap11 as well.

```
from spyne.application import Application
app = Application([HelloWorldService], 'spyne.examples.hello.http',
            in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
            out_protocol=Soap11(),
        )
```

You can check ref [link](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/02_helloworld.html).

Comment: thank you, but i want to use HttpRpc, also i dont know how to set tns at django app.